# Error when try to populate combo box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate a combo box and I am getting the following error:
Error: Duplicate md-option values are not allowed in a select. Duplicate value "companyPdfSequence.CompNo" found.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
<label>Company</label>
<md-select ng-model="selectedCompanySequencePdf" required ng-change="changeCompanySequencePdf(selectedCompanySequencePdf)">
    <md-option ng-repeat="companyPdfSequence in companiesPdfSequences" value="companyPdfSequence.CompNo">{{companyPdfSequence.Company}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

The value of companiesPdfSequences is:[{"CompNo":"1","Company":"Test1"},{"CompNo":"2","Company":"Test2"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
value="companyPdfSequence.CompNo"
```

To

```
value="{{companyPdfSequence.CompNo}}"
```

The binding of the attribute is text based. It's complaining that the value is identical because the variable is interpreted as plain text

```
"companyPdfSequence.CompNo" == "companyPdfSequence.CompNo"
```

Instead of the intent;

```
1 == 2
```